# Issues with angularjs directive and controller communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code is up on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qwf1WRelZOB0UALNVvqb?p=preview)

I'm having trouble setting the `ng-model` for a select tag via a directive, and passing this model to a function defined in the controller.

Comment: first: past here your code, second: use `=` instead `&`

Comment: also see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile): _& or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name_

Comment: @Grundy Thanks, was avoiding pasting the code here 'coz its better viewed on a "fiddle".

Comment: you should provide code here also, because in this case people can directly view your problem, also link could be broken after some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 selectedOption: "&"
```

From the documentation, "The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time"

What you want here is a bidirectionnal binding on an object so you should use "=" :

```
selectedOption: "=",
```

Working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/tfvTDviuGGFHVApg6Qcx?p=preview

Comment: _& or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name_, so this not only for function

Comment: @ThibaudL The `ng-model` of the select that I pass to the controller function is `undefined`, how can I get the proper ng-model value? http://plnkr.co/edit/Qwf1WRelZOB0UALNVvqb?p=preview

Comment: $scope.setSorting = function(field){ alert($scope.selectedOption); } you already have the value

Comment: It's not undefined, the event is just fired once at the initalisation with an undefined value but the second call is all right

Comment: Your function is an expression to be evaluated in the inner scope, so this time use "&" ^^ : here is a working plunker  :http://plnkr.co/edit/kwv7gMSbHQaHsABnk1Lb?p=preview